# Python stdin request coming before stdout prints

Tags: python, printing, stdin, raw-input

I've been trying to learn Python 3.3 recently and run into a problem. Here is the test code I am using:

```
print('should print before stdin')
x = raw_input('Enter something: ')
```

And here is what the output looks like:

```
>>something
should print before stdin
Enter something:
```

Why are the print statements coming after the stdin?

Comment: hmm the ">>" there says many things.
Try not running it from idle. Close idle and just double click the .py file , see if that works. If that's just the code you are running it should run fine.. at least on python < 3.0

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.X, the `raw_input("")` has been eliminated and so use `input()` instead.
Refer this [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input).

```
print('should print before stdin')
x = input('Enter something: ')
```

**Output**

```
should print before stdin
Enter something: yes

Process finished with exit code 0
```